# How to replace final_price.phtml with custom.phtml file only on product view?

Tags: product, magento2.3

Using **Magento ver. 2.3.0.** I want to display my custom final price block only on catalog product views. I try to replace `final_price.phtml` with my `custom_price.html` that I have created in `\app\design\frontend\company\themename\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\custom_price.phtml`

I understand that I need to edit `\app\design\frontend\company\themename\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

I have tried:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="custom.final.price" after="product.info.price" template="Magento_Catalog::product/price/custom_price.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

What XML part do I need to insert or edit to make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to put your `custom_price.phtml` content in :

> app/design/frontend/Company/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

You don't need the xml part.

Comment: After this customization, is anything issue happen when we upgrade magento?

Comment: No, this customisation stay in your current theme ;)

Comment: This is not the desired outcome, because the final_price.phtml gets shown on other parts of the site, eg. Category grid view, front page modules, etc...

I wish to apply this price block only on catalog product views where only 1 (single) product is displayed.

Comment: so you need to add custom price based on certain conditions only in product view page ?

Comment: @Fabler you have to customise your new `final_price.phtml` with your conditions

Comment: I did that and the final_price.phtml works but is displayed throughout entire frontend, where final_price.phtml is used.  This solution doesn't work only on single product view - where only 1 product is displayed.

Comment: @PЯINCƏ i just want to add,  disabled = "true"  in billing city text input area,  so i copied files from : app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml to app/code/local/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml, is this right practice? actually condition not applied.  What is the best practice in Magento 1.9.x

Comment: @zus sorry but it's not the same question and version, please open a new topic, it would be more interesting even for others :)